# How to speed up page loading time for images fetched from third party servers and external urls?

Tags: jquery, html, django, performance

At the moment, we have built a simple Django application that simply fetches images from ImgUr APIs using the following endpoint:

https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search

Then, it forwards the result to front-end for rendering which is simply HTML templates with jQuery.

However, images loading on the client side in the browser is very slow. How to speed it up?

I have traced the problem. It's the Waiting (TTFB)for images requests in HTTP. Here's a screen-shot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xBgh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please actively utilize Cache which keeps the image once called on the server. Facebook uses applications like Memcached to quickly show you recently accessed articles or images on the Facebook. Or, make sure your web browser is set to cache images. If you do not use this setting, it may be slower because each time you fetch the image from that website.

Comment: thank you, Won Peu, it's fast on server side though, but slow in fetching each image from imgur in HTTP request on the front end in the browser. since we are doing a different search each time, we can't count on caching.